# Laravel join query with two column in same table

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

**My code**

```
$result=DB::table('receipts')
      ->join('dealer_m','receipts.ToDealerID','dealer_m.DealerID')
      ->join('dealer_m','receipts.FromDealerID','dealer_m.DealerID')
      ->join('product_m','receipts.ProductID','product_m.ProductID')->get();
```

**table receipts**

```
Id | FromDealerId  | ToDealerId  |  ProductId
---+---------------+-------------+------------
1         1              2            1

2         1              3            1

3         3              1            1
```

**Table dealer_m**

```
DealerId | DealerName    
---------+-----------
  1         Dealer One
  2         Dealer Two
  3         Dealer Three
```

**Table product_m**

```
ProductId | ProductName
----------+-----------
    1       Product One
    2       Product Two
```

**Expected Output**

```
Id | FromDealerId  | ToDealerId  |  ProductId | FromDealerName | ToDealerName | ProductName
---+---------------+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------+------------


 1         1              2            1         Dealer One      Dealer Two  Product One

 2         1              3            1         Dealer One      Dealer Three  Product One

 3         3              1            1         Dealer Three    Dealer One   Product One
```

When I run my code it gets an error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
>   table/alias: 'dealer_m' (SQL: select '' from 'receipts' inner join
>   'dealer_m' on 'receipts'.'ToDealerID' = `dealer_m'.'DealerID' inner
>   join 'dealer_m' on 'receipts'.'FromDealerID' = 'dealer_m'.'DealerID'
>   inner join 'product_m' on 'receipts'.'ProductID' =
>   'product_m'.'ProductID')

How to solve this ???

Thank You

Comment: You need to alias the joins. `join('dealer_m AS dealer1')` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try This:

```
$results=DB::table('receipts')
      ->select('receipts.*','dealer_m1.DealerName as ToDealer','dealer_m2.DealerName as FromDealer','product_m.ProductName')
      ->join('dealer_m as dealer1','receipts.ToDealerID','dealer_m.DealerID')
      ->join('dealer_m as dealer2','receipts.FromDealerID','dealer_m.DealerID')
      ->join('product_m','receipts.ProductID','product_m.ProductID')->get();
```

You just need to give each joined table an alias

Now in your blade:

```
@foreach ($results as $result)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$result->Id}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->FromDealerId}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->ToDealerId}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->ProductId}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->FromDealer}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->ToDealer}}</td>
    <td>{{$result->ProductName}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Of course if you ever get stuck on what to call in your blade, just print our the collection to find the key => values or do dd($results); in the controller to inspect it before it gets to the view.

Comment: But how to get FromDealerName  and ToDealerName. Look at my expected output

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$result=DB::table('receipts')
      ->join('dealer_m as dealer_id','receipts.ToDealerID','dealer_m.DealerID')
      ->join('dealer_m as dealer_f_id','receipts.FromDealerID','dealer_m.DealerID')
      ->join('dealer_m as product_p_id','receipts.ProductID','product_m.ProductID')->get();
```

Comment: But how to get FromDealerName and ToDealerName. Look at my expected output